# How do I get more than 2k characters of an external js code for a bookmarklet?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I am working on making a auto updating bookmarklet and I was wondering if there was a way to get around the maximum external js code of 2000 characters? And if there is how would I do it?

Comment: What do you mean, what is this 2000 character limit? Is it that you can't put large amounts of text into the bookmark link?

Comment: Yes, you can only get 2k characters from an external link or that is what I have heard and it’s not letting me do more than 2k characters. The external link would be like yourwebsite.com/something/Bookmarklet.js

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Consider putting the text into a [userscript](https://www.tampermonkey.net/) instead - it not only doesn't have a (reasonable) length limit, it's also a whole lot easier to write, debug, and maintain, as well as more flexible options for when the code can run (such as automatically on pageload under the conditions you want).

For example, rather than a bookmarklet of

```
javascript: (() => {  alert('custom code here'); })();
```

if you want to do this on example.com, use the userscript

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name             My New Userscript
// @description      some description
// @include          /^https://example\.com/
// @grant            none
// ==/UserScript==

alert('custom code here');
```

and it'll run automatically.

You will need a userscript manager (browser extension) like Tampermonkey.